# REML estimation - matrix algebra internals

Tags: mathematical-statistics, panel-data, linear-algebra, reml

In the context of REML estimation there is the result (ignoring some constants) that (my interest is in the matrix algebra so some notation is suppressed):

$l(\mathbf V_0)=\log |\mathbf V_0| + \text{tr}(\mathbf V_0^{-1}\mathbf S) \tag{1}$

Where both $\mathbf V_0$ and $\mathbf S$ are symmetric and invertible. I am told that the following expression can be obtained from (1) by differentiating with respect to a parameter $\sigma_i$ of $\mathbf V_0$:

$\text{tr}\left[\mathbf V_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf V_0^{-1}}{\partial \sigma_i}\right]-\text{tr}\left[\frac{\partial \mathbf V_0^{-1}}{\partial \sigma_i}(\mathbf V_0 - \mathbf S)\right] \tag{2}$

I'm trying to see what steps got this, but am stuck.

Now I'm obviously lacking some machinery for dealing with these things but I don't know where to look. The issue is that, say, both terms in (1) are scalar, and we are differentiating w.r.t a scalar, so the it would seem the answer should be scalar. But my workings end up matrix valued. E.g.

$\frac{\partial \log |\mathbf V_0|}{\partial \sigma_i} = \mathbf V_0^{-1} \frac{\partial \mathbf V_0}{\partial \sigma_i} $

Clearly the trace gets involved wrapping it all up into a scalar, but I don't know how or why!

Comment: Now answered over at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819492/matrix-calculus-derivative-of-scalar-function-of-matrix-function-of-scalar